WebOptimizer cache busting not working on Azure
I am using ASP.NET Core Web Optimizer. It has cache busting feature that will append a unique string to the end of script or CSS links.
A sample of the appended string is like this: ....script.js?v=8UnFL4zesLGMnNgeUbnu9OOWly7_ES--Qx-E_tWr2NQ
I tested this on Azure App service and it worked as expected. I had ?v=blah for all css and JS bundles.
But, when I published the same on Azure Kubernetes, it didn't work.
What could be the reason?
Any other library recommended for cache busting in .NET 6?

does my solution works for you?


Any other library recommended for cache busting in .NET 6?

You can use front-end build tools like Webpack or Gulp to handle cache busting. These tools can rename the files with hash values in their names and update the HTML to reference the hashed files.

Kubernetes deployment serve's static files. In ASP.NET Core, static files are usually served from the wwwroot folder. Kubernetes setup should have the access to that folder.

If you use reverse proxy like Nginx, Check the below configuration setup to serve static files.
Nginx configuration:
location / {
    root /path/to/your/static/files;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}

Below Dockerfile copies the static files to the correct location and sets the correct permissions.
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet restore
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "testApp.dll"]

Deployment YAML:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: test-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: test-app
        image: test-docker-image
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - name: static-files
          mountPath: /app/wwwroot
      volumes:
      - name: static-files
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: test-pvc

This ingress configuration file routes requests to the application and allows serving static files.
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-app-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test-app.example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-app
            port:
              number: 80

Deployment status:



Thanks! I haven't tried your solution. Since I needed the fix urgently, I added datetime.now at the end the links.
